# Cambiar etiqueta Totales de Tabla Dinamica

Tags: excel

Saben si excel permite cambiar la etiqueta de totales de una tabla dinamica?

Por ejemplo

Total Cajas  y cambiarlo por Cajas Total

Comment: ¿No has probado a cambiarlo? A qué totales te refieres? En una tabla dinámica hay 3 tipos de totales. El total de columna, el total de fila y el total general. Si por etiqueta te refieres al nombre del campo cuando lo llevas al área de valores, que por defecto sale algo en plan `Sumade Cajas` o `CuentaDe Cajas`. sí, se puede cambiar manualmente, siempre y cuando el nombre que pongas no exista previamente. Cada nombre debe ser único.

Comment: Me refería a la etiqueta total de las filas. La verdad que vi que si cambias el nombre en una fila de totales la cambia en el resto de las filas que contengan más totales así que resuelto! Gracias.